# Is there any way to limit the number of pods a user can create in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I know we can limit users from accessing the resources by using autherisatoin (RBAC policy). But is there any ways to customise the number of pods or containers a user can create inside a cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's begin by having a Namespaces, Now we can limit the number of active pods where the phase is running or pending by using *ResourceQuota* for a namespace. 
For example

```
 apiVersion: v1
    kind: ResourceQuota
    metadata:
      name: quota
    spec:
      hard:
        metadata:
  name: object-counts
spec:
  hard:
    configmaps: "10"
    persistentvolumeclaims: "4"
    secrets: "10"
    pods:"20"
    services: "10"
    services.loadbalancers: "2"
```

I have attached the link for further research [resource-quota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/)

Comment: Its a good method. But i guess resource quotas are restricted to namespace only. Is there any way to implement resource quotas for a user?

Comment: As far as I know, By using RBAC you can say that a user, a group or a service account, can do these operations (create, list, watch etc) on these resources ( pods, svc, deployment).